# Cannot execute method in an NSPanel from a separate NSWindow in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, methods

I have a MacOS Objective-C project with a parent NSWindow and an NSPanel containing a TableView whose delegate and data source is a class called TableController. A Table Controller was placed in the Objects section of MainMenu.xib by cut and paste from another project. Table Controller does not appear in the controls made visible by Show Library. Methods to fill the TableView with data in TableController.m are executed when the parent form is loaded. I am able to execute these methods from a button on the NSPanel with `[MetadataView reloadData];` where MetadataView is an outlet for the TableView control on the NSPanel defined as `@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *MetadataView;` by ctrl-dragging the TableView into TableController.h.

If I try to make the method containing the reloadData command class-level rather than instance level (prefix + rather than -) in order to allow access from the parent form I get the error "Instance variable "MetadataView" accessed in a class method.

How can I make the method containing the reloadData command execute from a button click on the parent window?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to do. Is the `TableController` object a singleton? Is `MetadataView` a class (starts with a capital) or a property? Which object owns the table view? Which object owns the panel? Why do you want to use a class method?

Comment: "How can make the method containing the reloadData command execute from a button click on the parent window?" isn't a comprehensible sentence in English, right?

Comment: Grammar in final sentence fixed.

Comment: MetadataView is a property as defined in the question.

 I don't think TableController is a singleton. TableController.h contains `@interface TableController : NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate>`  followed by a series of properties and then `@end`. 

 How do you show the object which owns another object? Is it the top node in the object tree for controls such as TableView which are placed on a window? Owner is not shown in any  Inspector pane. I do not particularly want to use a class method -I just need to execute the code from the parent.

Comment: Is the table view owned by the table controller or by the panel? Which object is responsible for reloading the table view, the table controller or the panel? Is the parent window loaded from MainMenu.xib?

Comment: If ownership is defined  via the presence of a `(strong)` property, the TableView is not owned, but TableController is Outlet for  the TableView datasource and delegate and it is responsible for loading the TableView. In TableController.h @interface section there is a line `@property (weak) IBOutlet *MetadataView;`. The parent window is loaded from MainMenu.xib.

Comment: I was able to call the NSTableView reloadData command by creating an outlet TableView for the NSTableView in the NSPanel in AppDelegate.h and adding the line [_TableView reloadData]; in the action for the button on the parent form. When loadData executed it called the various methods in TableController.m which loaded the data image file metadata, and I was able to set the image file path in  standardUserDefaults from the parent form and read by the initialization method in the NSPanel, allowing me to select different files for which to show metadata. Not a full solution but maybe helpful.